# Why is left-margin and overlap problem with html2pdf.js package?

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I try to make pdf file with the [html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js?activeTab=readme). It works at some point very good, but I have two main problem.

The first, when the element which I select for rendering, is bigger than the window view height (when I can scroll the site), then in the rendered pdf document appears a some kind of white space on the left side, and because of that, the whole pdf content slides aside, so the right side is cut off.

The second problem is with the break-page property. With break-page property the problem is, that a small part of the newly broken page is on the previous page, and after every break-page, this small part will be bigger and bigger.

Also the first problem with the white space on the left side appears in Chrome and in Edge also, but in Firefox works just fine.

Here is the code from html2pdf:

```
const opt = {
        margin: [0,0,0,0], //top, left, bottom, right
        filename: 'myfile.pdf',
        image: {type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98},
        html2canvas: {
            scale: 2,
            scrollX: 0,
            scrollY: 0,
            y: 0,
            dpi: 400,
            // letterRendering: true,
            // windowWidth:500,
        },
        jsPDF: {
            unit: 'pt',
            format: 'a4',
            orientation: 'portrait',
            // compress: true,
            // marginLeft: 20,
            // marginRight: 20,
            // marginTop: 0,
            // floatPrecision: 'smart'
        },
        pagebreak: {mode: 'css', before: '.break-before', avoid: '.no-break'},
        // noPdfOpenParams: true
    };

const pdf = html2pdf().set(opt).from(page).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function (pdf) {
     window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'), '_blank');
})
```

The html file is just some regular div element with more nested html elements and with one image. I have the main div element like so `<div id="page" style="width: 595pt; padding: 0 20px;background-color: burlywood">` and in that div element I have child div elements with classname break-before, and for the div in which the image is, I have a classname no-break.

Here is how it looks when the `page` element is bigger then the window view height:

[image: White space]

Here is the break-page issue (at the third break-page):
[image: break-page issue]

Comment: You could try html3pdf, https://www.npmjs.com/package/html3pdf, which is a fork of html2pdf.js with some of the bug fixes pulled in, including some fixes for the pagebreak calculations

Answer (score 2):

I find out what is the cause of the white space on the right side. The problem was the 0.10.1 version, if someone has the same problem try it with the 0.9.3 version, for me it solved the problem.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.3/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-YcsIPGdhPK4P/uRW6/sruonlYj+Q7UHWeKfTAkBW+g83NKM+jMJFJ4iAPfSnVp7BKD4dKMHmVSvICUbE/V1sSw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

The second problem depends on the scale property. If I set it to 1, then works fine, sadly the quality isn't the best, would be nice to work with scale 2, that's a much better quility.